# how to write app that squares a float and displays it in console?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, floating-point

Sorry for the simple question, but i have an excercise where I have to write an Objective-C console app that squares a float and that displays resulting float in console, but i don't understand how to write it, can someong please show me how to write that code so I could understand?

I'm beginer to Objective C so thanks for the patience! :)

Comment: We won't do you homework! What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: No, it`s not my homework, I`m learning on my own, that`s why it is the hard part! :) Those are basics of the basics, and there I made app where to count, and then there was an excercise to make this thing, that i don`t understand  how to make at all ! :)

Comment: You might want to indicate which book or course you are following so people have an idea of what you do know.

Comment: I don`t have it with me, but maybe you could show how does a code looks like if you whant to make console app that squares a float on whatever what number, for example 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of a console application on the iPhone, but here you go:

Create a new project and edit your main.m from something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Change it to something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    float number = 3.14;
    float square = powf(number, 2.0);
    NSLog("%f^2=%f", number, square);
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Why did you leave the UIApplicationMain in here?